# Vuejs background image not work

Tags: html, css, vue.js

***Hello guys,***

I have a problem with back slash in background-image style in Vuejs and string replace in HTML not work and solution.

**URL from inspecting element**

`http://localhost:8000/storage/banar-pages\July2018\WPNrFE6eXopKnjMqjNgW.jpg`

**From DB**

`banar-pages\July2018\WPNrFE6eXopKnjMqjNgW.jpg`

**Code from component file**

```
<div class="block-entry fixed-background" :style="'background-image: url(' +link + '/storage/' + about.image +');'">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                <div class="cell-view simple-banner-height text-center">
                    <div class="empty-space col-xs-b35 col-sm-b70"></div>
                    <h1 class="h1 light">{{ about.name }}</h1>
                    <div class="title-underline center"><span></span></div>
                    <div class="simple-article light transparent size-4">{{ about.details }}</div>
                    <div class="empty-space col-xs-b35 col-sm-b70"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Thank you**

Comment: What're you asking exactly, and what's the problem? The forward slashes to specify directory are improper, but if that's coming from your database that's what needs changed.

Comment: I need to replace image link it but flage not work `image.replace('/\\/g', '/')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to replace image link it but flage not work `image.replace('/\\/g', '/')`

It looks like you're incorrectly passing a string as the first argument to [`String#replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), which would result in a literal replacement (i.e., it would replace the first occurrence of `/\/g` in the string):

```js
console.log('XX/\\/gXX/\\/gXX'.replace('/\\/g', '/'))
```

Remove the quotes from the first argument to [make it a regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```js
console.log('\\path\\to\\foo.png'.replace(/\\/g, '/'))
```

Then, your Vue template could be similar to this:

```
<div :style="'background-image: url(' +link.replace(/\\/g, '/') + '/storage/' + about.image.replace(/\\/g, '/') +');'">
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      link: 'http:\\placekitten.com',
      about: {
        image: '\\100\\100'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.dummy {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="dummy"
       :style="`background-image: url(${link.replace(/\\/g, '/')}${about.image.replace(/\\/g, '/')})`">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a method for processing that string and returning a revised URL:

```
methods: {
    prepareURL(string) {
        return string.replace('/\\/g', '/');
    }
}
```

Component code:

```
<div class="block-entry fixed-background" :style="'background-image: url(' +link + '/storage/' + prepareURL(about.image) +');'">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
            <div class="cell-view simple-banner-height text-center">
                <div class="empty-space col-xs-b35 col-sm-b70"></div>
                <h1 class="h1 light">{{ about.name }}</h1>
                <div class="title-underline center"><span></span></div>
                <div class="simple-article light transparent size-4">{{ about.details }}</div>
                <div class="empty-space col-xs-b35 col-sm-b70"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```